# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two model, one as follow

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, class_name: 'Assignment', foreign_key: :assignment_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: :group_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And another model

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course, class_name: 'Course', foreign_key: :course_id
  has_many :questions, class_name: 'Question', foreign_key: :question_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

These two has relationship one to many i.e a course can have many assignments but an assignment belongs to a course.

In my `assignment/index.html.erb` view I have following form

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "assignments", action: "new"}, method: "get", class: "nifty_form") do %>
    <%= select_tag "course", options_from_collection_for_select(Course.all, :id, :name) %> <br /><br />
    <%= submit_tag("New Assignment") %>
<% end %>
```

New method of my assignments_controller.rb

```
def new
    @course = Course.find(params[:course])
    @assignment = @course.assignments.build
  end
```

When I submit the above form I get error at this line `@assignment = @course.assignments.build`

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in AssignmentsController#new
unknown attribute: assignment_id
```

assignment_id and course_id are not a column in the any of the table. How to fix this error?

Also I am new to rails. Since I have one to many relation, I am trying to create database as `@assignment = @course.assignments.build` is this the right way? I mean do I have to write `@course.assignments.build` or just `@assignment = Assignment.new` is okay? Also the way I wrote the relationships with foreign key is it correct?

Comment: As there is no need to add foreign_key: :assignment_id in course model. It automatically be understandable when you define has_many relationship.Please make sure your course table has assignment_id as a column. Please write down the required migration if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `belongs_to` table MUST have the foreign keys defined as columns in the table. How do you think the records will be linked, otherwise?

So your `assignments` table should have an integer column `course_id`.  Create it with a migration.

Then all you need is...

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
```

and...

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
```

Then this will work...

```
@assignment = @course.assignments.build
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify `class_name` and `foreign_key`, when you follow convention, as it is in your case.

`@assignment = @course.assignments.build` is a right way, because you want to specify relationship between course and assignment. You can do this: `@assignment = Assignment.new(course: @course)`, but use first method.

Edit: I assume that you have `assignment_id` attribute in `Course`:)

Comment: but I am getting this error unknown attribute: assignment_id

Comment: In both table Course and Assignment, I have 4 columns id, name, created_at and updated_at

Comment: So this is it. You have create a migration, and add foreign key (`assignment_id `) to `Course`. Check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) for references